# Getting supported TLS version from server

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2

I have a application in which I want to set TLS version but it will depend on the server . I want to set the TLS version which server is supporting and it may be different for different server so is there any API and method to get the supported TLS version of any server in java or android?

I would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to know which version the server supports up-front.
In SSL/TLS the client will start the handshake announcing the highest version it is willing to support and the server will just reply with the best version it can do and which is not higher than the clients version.

The only thing where you would need such knowledge is if you are dealing with a broken server which does not properly handle unknown versions. In this case browsers retry with a lower version (i.e. retry with TLS 1.0 instead of TLS 1.2) in the hope that this will work. If this worked they will remember that the server is broken and need to be handled with a lower version for future connections. But this kind of fallback is mostly done within browsers and other applications just give up on broken servers.

Comment: I need to do it in android application so could you please let me piece of code which I can use to get the version which is given by server and set at the client side.

Comment: @user499: like I said: "There is no need to know which version the server supports up-front". This is true for Android too.

Comment: Android  support diferent TLS version on the basis of API Version so which version client will use in handshake or I can manually set the version on the basis of Android API version in client app.

Comment: @user499: unless you set an explicit version or use a library which sets an explicit version it should offer the best version supported by the API to the server. See also http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/ for information on how to enable specific versions.

Comment: But I faced with one big problem: built-in browser (WebView), what we use for authentication, supports TLS 1.1+ only from 4.4 KitKat. Android OS supports TLS 1.1+ from 16 API version, but WebView supports TLS 1.1+ only from 19 API version. I didn’t find opportunity to set TLS protocol to WebView manually. So we can’t login in system through web on devices below KItKat. I checked this on real devices Samsung 4.1.2 and Asus 4.2.2 , and emulator 4.3.1

Comment: @user499: this is a client side limitation and getting up-front information on what the server supports will not help here. Thus this follow-up is outside the original question. I recommend to ask a new question specifically on how to support better TLS versions in WebView etc especially since I myself cannot help you here.